# Laravel Failed to open stream error with Sail

Tags: laravel, laravel-sail

I'm attempting to run Sail within my Laravel project and it all starts as expected but when I go to https://localhost I get an error 500 in the browser and this error in the log

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught ErrorException: file_put_contents(/home/harry/booker/storage/framework/views/31194b376a867d7e5a56653be65b2bc7a5c4040b.php): Failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Filesystem/Filesystem.php:187
```

I know the directory `/storage/framework/views` exists as I can see it in my code editor. I've tried deleting my `bootstrap/cache/config.php`, running `php artisan config:clear && php artisan config:cache` but with no luck? The bootstrap config.php file has the correct reference to the views folder. I've also made sure the permissions are correct by running `sudo chmod -R 755 storage/`

Comment: That is a cached view that is registered but no longer exist

Answer (score 2):

You mention the `/storage/framework/views` directory exists, but does it contain the requested file `31194b376a867d7e5a56653be65b2bc7a5c4040b.php`?

Also, can you try running the following in your terminal:

```
php artisan optimize:clear
php artisan view:cache
```

This should empty all Laravel caches and rebuild the views cache.